# Placing a picture inside a div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm want to put a picture inside a div, with a specified width an height. However the image is still bigger than the div size:

```
    <div class="Designs">

        <p>Designs</p>

            <div class="Thumbnails" data-animation="animated pulse">

                <a href="images/Halloween/bat.png"><img src="images/Halloween/bat_sm.png" width="130" height="76"/></a>

            </div>      
    </div> <!-- End Designs -->


<style>

#content .Designs .Thumbnails img {
margin: .3em 0;
min-width: 0;

}

#content .Designs .Thumbnails {
width: 143px;
height: 95px;
margin: auto;

}

</style>
```

My website for reference: http://mast.salemstate.edu/itc18244/Portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these in your CSS code:-

```
img {
     min-width: 246px;
     float: left; 
     margin-right: 2em;
     margin-top: 6px;
     margin-left: 1em;
    }
```

With:-

```
img {
     min-width: 0px;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 2em;
     margin-top: 6px;
     margin-left: 1em;
    }
```

Comment: That worked for my picture, but for the slideshow picture it still not centered in the div? So I made two additional divs for the arrows (which for some reason can't set the width for them) and want the "bat" picture to be centered of its own div

Comment: This will surely work................             //   #theDiv
{
    width: 690px;
    height: 483px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#theImg
{
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 400px;
}​

Comment: Changed that & still the same, take a look at my site if you haven't and youll see what I mean. I think there's a css rule that may need an override? http://mast.salemstate.edu/itc18244/Portfolio/

Comment: okey you can try this too...  #thediv{
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle 
   }

Comment: hmm..well now interestingly enough now the pic is on the bottom left, only thing that was different I added was  display: table-cell;

Comment: change the display of big box img to inline-block and see if it works... if this doesnt work try removing the position styles from both div and img... this is the best i can help with, sry abt dat :-(

Answer (score 4):

You have there `min-width: 246px` in your `styles.css` in line 44.

You can overwrite that using:

```
.Thumbnails img {min-width: 0;}
```

Or better, set `min-width` to images where you need that, not to all images (you more specific selector than `img`).

Answer (score 3):

On line 44 of your styles.css file you have:

```
img {
min-width: 246px;
float: left;
margin-right: 2em;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 1em;
}
```

The `min-width: 246px;` rule is taking precedence. You either need to remove that rule, or override it.